# jQuery not seeing "a" anchor tag for some odd reason?

Tags: wordpress, jquery, anchor

Are there **any instances where jQuery is unable to recognize or select an anchor tag** regardless of how implicit the selector? The recent update to wordpress seems to have made my (admin) modal-window anchor tags invisible to any scripts I write.

```
<a href="#TB_inline?width=600&amp;height=550&amp;inlineId=ss-edit-image-box" data-id="6285" id="6285" title="Edit Individual Image Info" class="edit-image thickbox prettylink" style="display: inline;">» Edit 6285</a>
```

That is a modal window link. Clicking on it brings the modal-window. That in fact works.

But getting ajax to "post" does not happen. It seems my attempt to select the anchor tag by its class is still not giving anything.

```
//get_image_ajax
$(document).on('click', '.edit-image', function (e) {

    e.preventDefault();

    var data = {
        action: 'ss_professional_ajax',
        security: '<?php echo $ajax_nonce; ?>',
        image_id: $(this).attr('id'),
    };

    $.post(ajaxurl, data, function (response) {
        $('#ss-edit-image-box-content').empty();
        $('#' + loading_icon).show();
        $('#ss-edit-image-box-content').append(response);
        $('#' + loading_icon).hide();
    });
    return false;
});
```

Its very important to note this problem happened with the wordpress 3.6 update. Before everything was fine.

Comment: It might be easier to see the code you're using. It is possible that it is an error on your end and not jQuery.

Comment: Show us how your binding to the anchor in question, maybe it is created dynamically and you are binding code is wrong

Comment: Its a bonus to even get an answer. Updating original post.

Comment: @Huangism that might be the case. These are ajax-delivered results. i'm using "on" to get the "live" results, but maybe thats a problem. It should not be, since I'm still able to get jquery interactions from the other elements which have "add class" functions tied to them.

Comment: Update - when I change it to a <span> it does fine, and posts (although the modal does not fire) so its possible wordpress is silently sabotaging any actions delivered on the modal-trigger process.

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously a basic jquery operation being blocked by wordpress 3.6 modal/thickbox admin area for some reason.

I got around it simply by using a **$('#whatever').trigger('click');** to launch the modal window, using the human-clicked element to fire the event instead.

Strange nobody could answer this with the "whats really happening" scenerio. We'll leave it to the 1/100,000,00 chance someone else runs into the same issue since 3.6